# How to highlight List entry for a short time like in other apps?

Tags: javascript, sencha-touch-2

I need some help in Sencha Touch 2.3. 
I want to implement the following functionality:
If user taps on a newslist entry it should be highlighted and then go back normal for a short time, like in Whatsapp (If you tap on a contact to chat) or in android contacts if you tap on a contact.

Is there a integrated fnction in Sencha Touch?

Thanks:-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

are you trying to achieve something like [this](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/4vn)  ?  You can simply add and itemtap eventlistener to your list just defer the deselectAll() call for that list.

Code snippet below:

```
itemtap: function(comp, index, target, record, e, eOpts) {
            Ext.Function.defer(function(a) {
                a.deselectAll(true);
            },
            1000, this, [comp]);
        }
```